# Pandas Dataframe add column with lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to add a column to my Pandas Dataframe with a random generated code of two uppercase letters. For the random code generation i wrote a function, but when i add it to the dataframe it gives me only NaN as result. Any idea how to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

def generateCode():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

df['Code'] = df.apply(lambda x: generateCode())

print(df)
```

gives the output:

```
            Brand  Price Code
0     Honda Civic  22000  NaN
1  Toyota Corolla  25000  NaN
2      Ford Focus  27000  NaN
3         Audi A4  35000  NaN
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Just Add `df['Code'] = df.apply(lambda x: generateCode(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for processing per each value:

```
df['Code'] = df['Brand'].apply(lambda x: generateCode())

print(df)
            Brand  Price Code
0     Honda Civic  22000   AY
1  Toyota Corolla  25000   EN
2      Ford Focus  27000   VN
3         Audi A4  35000   ZZ
```

Or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing per rows:

```
df['Code'] = df.apply(lambda x: generateCode(), axis=1)

print(df)
            Brand  Price Code
0     Honda Civic  22000   AY
1  Toyota Corolla  25000   EN
2      Ford Focus  27000   VN
3         Audi A4  35000   ZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t ask me why, but this actually worked:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

def generateCode():
    print(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
    return random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

df['Code'] = df.Brand.map(lambda x: generateCode())

print(df)
```

If someone can explain why this worked, I would be grateful

Comment: Actually I´ve been making some prints and I think the problems was that you didnt specify a column so it returned a whole row instead of just a series with each row value. `df.Brand.apply(lambda x: generateCode())`, this also worked by the way